# Why is the expression false and true evaluating to true? (python 2.7)

Tags: python

I have two boolean variables in my program called after and late. Just to make sure each variable got the right value, I tested each one with the following command:

```
print(after)
print(late)
```

The program prints

```
false
true
```

as expected. However, when I run the following code:

```
if after and late:
  print('true and true')
elif after and (not late):
  print('true and false')
elif (not after) and late:
  print('false and true')
elif (not after) and (not late):
  print('false and false')
```

the program prints

```
'true and true'
```

which means that the expression after and late is evaluating to true. Why is this evaluating to true even though true and false should yield false?

Comment: Are `after` and `late` strings, perhaps?

Comment: a lil more snippet would be helpful

Comment: They're definitely not booleans.  Check the case.  Python's booleans are Capitalized.

Comment: print(type(after), type(later))

Comment: If the answer satisfies please mark and close it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> print(True and False)
False
```

[**Boolean**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values) values have a capital letter in the beginning. I guess you use strings. You could check that with `type(after)`.

You don't need to divide all the cases manually to "debug" your program. That's not the way Python was intended for...
Just `print` the evaluated code `print(after+' and '+late)`, use `type` like me above or use your interactive python console to play around.

Comment: Thanks. I just tested it and they were strings.